# MVC application data only populated when code changed

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm getting a very strange problem which has been happening since I switched to Local IIS from IIS Express.

My data only populates *after* I make changes to the code. If I don't make changes but run the application or start the website, no data is being retrieved.

I don't think it's a problem with the database. Does anyone have any idea what could be going on here?

Edit: The code I'm using to make the call to a Couchbase database is:

```
   var docs = _interceptorToCouchbase.GetView(Bucket.Fact, "User", "GetUserList").Stale(StaleMode.False).Execute<IViewRow>("User", "GetUserList").Select(user => Convert.ToString(user.Info.Values.FirstOrDefault(), CultureInfo.CurrentCulture))
```

However, I don't think that's relevant to this question. I don't even understand how Couchbase would *know* when I've changed the code. I'm getting the impression that there's something crucial that I'm missing relating to running ASP.NET applications on the web.

Comment: Are you using Entity Framework?

Comment: We need more information like code and sample images, otherwise it is very hard to determine the root cause.